# Python quick-sort parallel sort slower than sequential

Tags: python, sorting, multiprocessing, quicksort

Need some help with code below, there have to be something wrong with it  because I get better results with sequential sort than with parallel version.I'm new to python and especially parallel programming and any help would be welcome.

```
import random, time
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe,cpu_count
from copy import deepcopy


def main():
    create_list = [random.randint(1,1000) for x in range(25000)]



    #sequential sort
    sequentialsortlist=deepcopy(create_list)


    start = time.time()
    sorted2 =quicksort(sequentialsortlist)
    elapsed = time.time() - start
    print("sequential sort")
    print(elapsed)




    time.sleep(4)

    #Parallel quicksort.
    parallelsortlist = deepcopy(create_list)

    start = time.time()
    n = cpu_count()

    pconn, cconn = Pipe()


    p = Process(target=quicksortParallel,
                args=(parallelsortlist, cconn, n,))
    p.start()

    lyst = pconn.recv()


    p.join()

    elapsed = time.time() - start
    print("Parallels sort")
    print(elapsed)


def quicksort(lyst):

    less = []
    pivotList = []
    more = []
    if len(lyst) <= 1:
        return lyst
    else:
        pivot = lyst[0]
        for i in lyst:
            if i < pivot:
                less.append(i)
            elif i > pivot:
                more.append(i)
            else:
                pivotList.append(i)
        less = quicksort(less)
        more = quicksort(more)
        return less + pivotList + more

def quicksortParallel(lyst, conn, procNum):


   less = []
   pivotList = []
   more = []

   if procNum <= 0 or len(lyst) <= 1:
       conn.send(quicksort(lyst))
       conn.close()
       return
   else:
       pivot = lyst[0]
       for i in lyst:
           if i < pivot:
               less.append(i)
           elif i > pivot:
               more.append(i)
           else:
               pivotList.append(i)


   pconnLeft, cconnLeft = Pipe()

   leftProc = Process(target=quicksortParallel,
                      args=(less, cconnLeft, procNum - 1))


   pconnRight, cconnRight = Pipe()
   rightProc = Process(target=quicksortParallel,
                      args=(more, cconnRight, procNum - 1))


   leftProc.start()
   rightProc.start()


   conn.send(pconnLeft.recv()+pivotList + pconnRight.recv())
   conn.close()

   leftProc.join()
   rightProc.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that the overhead of setting up your parallel execution environment and then re-joining it at the end is more expensive then the performance increase gained from the parallelism.

Multi-processing actually forks sub-processes. That's very expensive. It only makes sense to do this if the amount of work done in each thread is *very* large.

This kind of problem is actually pretty common when people neivly try and parallelize code. It's pretty common that for many 'reasonable' workloads the single-threaded implementation winds up being faster.

Answer (score 0):

There is a cost associated with starting/terminating a process. Interprocess communication is not free, either. So the overhead is just too big.